# Save a table with data from a class

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I would like to save and reread the data that are in "Cours". I'm trying today with Userdefaults but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
var Cours = [CoursParNiveau]()
```

Class:

```
class CoursParNiveau: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var DateLecon:String?
    var HoraireLecon: String?

    init (Date: String, Horaire: String){
        self.DateLecon = Date
        self.HoraireLecon = Horaire
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(DateLecon, forKey: "Date")
        aCoder.encode(HoraireLecon, forKey: "Horaire")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.DateLecon = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Date") as? String
        self.HoraireLecon = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Horaire") as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: “but it doesn't work” isn’t a question, please explain what your issue is

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`Codable`** to *encode/decode* `data` for saving/fetching from `UserDefaults`.

Conform `CoursParNiveau` to `Codable` and implement `enum CodingKeys` to define custom `keys` you want to use while *encoding/decoding*, i.e.

```
class CoursParNiveau: Codable {
    var DateLecon: String?
    var HoraireLecon: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case DateLecon = "Date"
        case HoraireLecon = "Horaire"
    }
}
```

**Saving to `UserDefaults`:**

```
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(Cours)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "CoursParNiveau")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Fetching from `UserDefaults`:**

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "CoursParNiveau") {
    do {
        self.Cours = try JSONDecoder().decode([CoursParNiveau].self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```